# Can you please tell whats wrong with this

Tags: python, syntax

**Can you tell me what is wrong with this error?***************

```
codio@random-media:~/workspace$ python final.py
File "final.py", line 4
  return f'print("{phrase}")\n'
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


def createOutput(lang, phrase):
    if lang == "python":
        return f'print("{phrase}")\n'
    if lang == "c++":
        return f'cout << "{phrase}\\n";\n'
    if lang == "c":
        return f'printf("{phrase}\\n");\n'
    return ""
```

Comment: Even on Python versions where that would be syntactically valid, it's not a thing that makes any sense to write.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's difficult to deduce the problem using the traceback alone.

Comment: You are using python2?

Comment: Python reports when the parser realizes there is a syntax error but the problem may be a line or two above. Post more of the code leading up to this error so we can see.

Comment: I updated the indentation. Let me know if its correct. This may well be a problem with python 3 syntax while using python 2. Add version to the question so we know.

Comment: You can get version from `import sys;print(sys.version)`.

Comment: indentation didn't work

Comment: i"m using Codio online compiler

Comment: @arby - Works for me. Are you getting an indentation error or the same syntax error? Several of us suspect you are using python version < 3.6 so `'print("{}")\n'.format(var)` is what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

F strings are not supported in python2.

Use format

```
'print("{}")\n'.format(var)
```

Or use Python 3.6+ and run the code

Comment: i used Codio online compiler

Comment: Check the python version

Comment: def createOutput(lang, phrase):
    if lang == "python":
        return f'print("{phrase}")\n'
    if lang == "c++":
        return f'cout << "{phrase}\\n";\n'
    if lang == "c":
        return f'printf("{phrase}\\n");\n'
    return ""

Comment: @arby - can you put that in a code block in the original question just like the syntax error you posted so we can see it more clearly?

Comment: Can you just remove the " f " string and use format. Please try

Comment: @arby - Python f strings are for python version 3.6 and following .That's why we are asking you.

Comment: didn't work too, I'm using the latest version of python

Comment: @arby - Are you saying you are using python 3.8.2?

Comment: It works in Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01)